# Populate textarea based on which dropdown has been changed

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, textarea

My issue is I am trying to update a `textarea`'s text based on which dropdown was changed.

So if dropdown 1 is changed the `textarea` updates, but if dropdown 2 is changed it would update the `textarea` again. My current code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function responseText(product) {
      document.getElementById("resptext").value = document.getElementById(product).value;
    }

    function CopyToClipboard() {
      let selector = document.querySelector('#resptext')
      selector.select()
      document.execCommand('copy')
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="float: left;">Dropdown 1<br />
    <select id="thingama" onClick="responseText(thingama); ">
      <option></option>
      <option value="test 1">1</option>
      <option value="test 2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div style="float: left;">Dropdown 2<br />
    <select id="thingama1" onClick="responseText(thingama1); ">
      <option></option>
      <option value="test 3">3</option>
      <option value="test 4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <textarea id="resptext" style=" width: 600px;  height: 400px;"></textarea>
  <button onClick="CopyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe my issue is in how I am trying to pass the variable, but I am missing something that I believe will be super simple. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have few issues on your code, first you should use onchange, then you should use this instead of name

```html
<!html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function responseText(product){
  document.getElementById("resptext").value=product.value;
}
function CopyToClipboard() {

  let selector = document.querySelector('#resptext')
  selector.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float: left;">Dropdown 1<br />
<select id="thingama" onchange="responseText(this); ">
<option></option>
<option value="test 1">1</option>
<option value="test 2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="float: left;">Dropdown 2<br />
<select id="thingama1" onchange="responseText(this); ">
<option></option>
<option value="test 3">3</option>
<option value="test 4">4</option>
</select>
</div>
<textarea id="resptext" style=" width: 600px;  height: 400px;"></textarea>

<button onClick="CopyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just our of curiosity, why is onchange better than onclick here?

Comment: onclick not checking for change, it just check element clicked, click may not change element value

Comment: Ahhh makes sense, Thanks again!